# C# image-change source

Tags: c#, wpf, image

How to change image source in c# of image1 , WPF?

```
<Image 
            Visibility="Visible"
           Name="image1"
            Source="/Panorama-Kocka;component/slike/kocka.PNG"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="0" 
            Stretch="Fill"
            />
```

Comment: Your image has a name: `image1`. So you'd do `image1.Source = "C:\my\new\image.png";`, or something like that. It all depends what you want to do.

Comment: I want to change image source in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having the same problem as you and doing some reading, I discovered the solution - Pack URIs.

I did the following in code:

```
Image finalImage = new Image();
finalImage.Width = 80;
...
BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage()
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ApplicationName;component/Resources/logo.png");
logo.EndInit();
...
finalImage.Source = logo;
```

The URI is broken out into parts:

```
Authority: application:///

Path: The name of a resource file that is compiled into a referenced assembly. The path must conform to the following format: AssemblyShortName[;Version][;PublicKey];component/Path
    AssemblyShortName: the short name for the referenced assembly.
    ;Version [optional]: the version of the referenced assembly that contains the resource file. This is used when two or more referenced assemblies with the same short name are loaded.
    ;PublicKey [optional]: the public key that was used to sign the referenced assembly. This is used when two or more referenced assemblies with the same short name are loaded.
    ;component: specifies that the assembly being referred to is referenced from the local assembly.
    /Path: the name of the resource file, including its path, relative to the root of the referenced assembly's project folder.
```

The three slashes after application: have to be replaced with commas:

```
Note: The authority component of a pack URI is an embedded URI that points to a package and must conform to RFC 2396. Additionally, the "/" character must be replaced with the "," character, and reserved characters such as "%" and "?" must be escaped. See the OPC for details.
```

And of course, make sure you set the build action on your image to Resource.